# Math to get relative scale from level stack

Tags: java, math

Apologies for the horrible title.  I spent 10 minutes trying to explain this in one sentence and failed.

Although the application prompting this question is in Java (Android), I think it's pretty general and applicable to any language.  Psuedo-code (or just plain English) replies are welcome.  I wasn't sure if I should just tag all the common languages, but that seemed a little spammy.

My actual requirement is a little less simply structured than some of the examples that follow, but I'll try to present the idea simply and clearly.

Say I've got 5 "image levels", each level is double the size of the previous level:

- level 1 = 100px square
- level 2 = 200px square
- level 3 = 400px square
- level 4 = 800px square
- level 5 = 1600px square

These image levels all show the same thing but with varying degree of detail (the smallest image shows only major features; the largest image shows fine detail).

Assume we never want to scale an image larger to avoid distortion, and should only perform transforms on an image that make it smaller, the goal being to use the largest appropriate image with the least amount of scaling.

Say a user is on level 3 (400px) and performs a scale operation to 1.8.  The new size would be (1.8 * 400 = 720), which means I should show level 4 (800px), scaled to 0.9 (800 * 0.9 = 720).

Another example - a user is on level 2 and scales to 5.2.  Size would be (5.2 * 200 = 1040).  So show level 5, scaled to 0.65 (1600 * 0.65 = 1040).

Knowing the sizes of the levels, the logic is pretty simple.

1. Take the size of the current level, multiply it by the user scale.  Call this `newSize`
2. Find the lowest level whose size is larger than that number.  Call this `targetLevel`
3. Divide `newSize` by the size of the `targetLevel`.  This is the relative scale.

Now let's say I don't actually know the actual sizes of the images, and there's no way to get to them, and perhaps they're not really exactly the size they should be (although they will always respresent double the previous level), and there might be any number of levels.

Using just the current level, and the user-defined scale value, what math or logic is involved in getting back the appropriate destination level and it's relative (new) scale?

More examples...

- User on Level 5 scales to 0.2.  New Level should be 3, new scale should be 0.8
- User on Level 1 scales to 3.6.  New Level should be 3, new scale should be 0.9
- User on Level 1 scales to 5.0.  New level should be 4, new scale should be 0.625
- User on Level 2 scales to 5.0.  New level should be 5, new scale should be 0.625
- User on Level 3 scales to 3.0.  New level should be 5, new scale should be 0.75
- User on Level 4 scales to 0.3.  New level should be 3, new scale should be 0.6
- User on Level 4 scales to 1.6.  New level should be 5, new scale should be 0.8
- User on Level 4 scales to 0.6.  New level should be 4, new scale should be 0.6 [1]

[1] probably obvious, but anything less than 1 but greater than 0.5 would stay the same

TYIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "levels" can be defined by the following exponential function (with your levels starting at 1): 
[image: level(x) = baseSize * 2<sup>x-1</sup>]

For simplicity, let's assume you have [image: s<sub>x</sub>] (scale) and [image: level(x)] and you're trying to find [image: level(y)].

Seeing how [image: level(x)] is defined, you can see that

[image: 2<sup>a</sup> * level(x) = level(x+a)]

However, your scale is not given in neat powers of 2 like that, so you can find a with the following (rounding up as per your scenario):

[image: ⌈log<sub>2</sub>(s<sub>x</sub>)⌉ = a]

Which means that [image: y = x + ⌈log<sub>2</sub>(s<sub>x</sub>)⌉] and [image: level(y) = 2<sup>⌈log<sub>2</sub>(s<sub>x</sub>)⌉</sup> * level(x)]

Now that we have the new level, we have the following equation:
[image: s<sub>x</sub> * level(x) = s<sub>y</sub> * level(y)<br>]
[image: s<sub>x</sub> * baseSize * 2<sup>x-1</sup> = s<sub>y</sub> * baseSize * 2<sup>y-1</sup>]
[image: s<sub>x</sub> * 2<sup>x-1</sup> / 2<sup>y-1</sup> = s<sub>y</sub>]
[image: s<sub>x</sub> * 2<sup>x-y</sup> = s<sub>y</sub>]

/edit
Yes, that's what 2<sup>x-1</sup> means.

- s<sub>x</sub> is just some constant that goes with x (in this case it's your scale), likewise, s<sub>y</sub> is some constant that goes with y.
- The weird square brackets with just the top bit (⌈ ⌉) are just the ceiling function (`Math.ceil`).
- Logarithms are the inverse of exponentiation. Logarithms are defined as the following: if a<sup>c</sup> = b, then log<sub>a</sub>(b) = c. For instance, log<sub>2</sub>(8) = 3 because 2<sup>3</sup> = 8. Is anything else confusing?

/java sample

```
int newLevel = oldLevel + (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(oldScale) / Math.log(2));
double newScale = oldScale * Math.pow(2, oldLevel - newLevel);
```

We have to use the [change of base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) formula for logarithms because [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) only provides [log<sub>e</sub>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) and [log<sub>10</sub>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10%28double%29). It might be worthwhile to create a constant for `Math.log(2)` so you aren't constantly recalculating it.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is the correct answer, but honestly it's way over my head - I'm not even clear on the notation.  Any chance you could explain as if I dropped out in the 9th grade?  TYIA

Comment: @Big MoMo Changed the equations to images to make them a bit clearer. What parts are confusing you? I'll gladly explain

Comment: honestly, pretty much all of it.  i assume "2x-1" means "2 to the power of x minus 1", but that's about it.  everything else is way over my head.  i have no idea what the notation means.  sorry.  i think what you're describing is probably very clear and not that advanced - i feel like an idiot.

Comment: @Jeffrey: See also [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) and [ceiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: @Big MoMo I added some explanations in an edit, let me know if anything is still confusing.

Comment: @Jeffrey accept and +1 - good answer and clarification.  i understand a little more now after your explanation (log now makes sense), but still some of it is eluding me - any chance you could write that out as code?  any language should be fine.  either way, thanks

Comment: @Big MoMo It's only two lines of code, so sure. There you go.

Comment: @Jeffrey very nice.  I'll definitely spend some time looking into basic math notation so I can understand what's going on here, but I'll use the logic right away.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeffrey sorry to come back.  That particular bit of code rolls into negatives if the net scale and level are low (e.g., level 5 / scale 0.1, or level 0 / scale 0.4) - passing Math.max(0, newLevel) before calculating newScale seems to fix it - do you see any issues with doing so?

Comment: @Big MoMo Level 0, scale .4 should roll into negatives. If 0 is your lowest level, you don't need to calculate a new level and scale if you're scaling it smaller, just return the old level and scale.

Answer (score 1):

This simple [matching game](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) uses `enum Game`to specify the constants needed for the game's four levels. By overriding `toString()` (and slightly violating the case convention for constants) the `Game.values()` can be used to populate the level selection `gameCombo` directly. Changing levels then requires little more than replacing the components and invoking `validate()` on the enclosing `Container`.

Comment: This has little to do with math, but it might be useful once you get the scale factors worked out.

Comment: thanks for the link - i'm not actually working on a game, but i'll definitely dive into it to see how you handled levels once i get this particular piece finished up.

Answer (score 0):

so far...

```
public static void getZoom(int currentLevel, double userScale){
        double ns = (1 << (currentLevel - 1)) * userScale;
        int newLevel = 1;
        int ts = 1;
        while(ts < ns){
            ts <<= 1;
            newLevel++;
        }
        double newScale = ns / ts;
        System.out.println(newLevel + ", " + newScale);
    }
```