# switching between JTabbedPanes to be displayed in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jtabbedpane

I have a math game that has two modes, each with five difficulties. I wish to give the players a choice to see a chart representation of their game history, as well as a table representation (for my purposes; this is a beta-test). The table part, I have already done, but the problem is now with implementing my chart idea. My idea is thus:

- Make a menu with only two menu items (the two game modes)
- For each of these modes, make a JTabbedPane that will house the five charts (the five difficulties)

The problem with this is, although I can make the menu items mutually exclusive (trivial!), making it to where only one JTabbedPane displays is another animal. I could have one item selected from the menu by default (which will display one JTabbedPane by default), and I know that I can check which JMenuItem was selected, and then do something like this:

```
if (otherTabbedPaneIsShowing)
{
    tableFrame.remove(otherTabbedPane);
}
tableFrame.add(desiredTabbedPane);
```

//This is pseudocode, of course, but you get the idea.
My main concern about this approach is the hidden algorithmic complexity. Will this be a time-consuming effort, and if so, is there a "better" way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: I had no idea that existed! I am not currently in-school, and I am learning so much from experiences like this and people like you! Thank you; I might have to research an example of this; I cannot find it in my (old) Java 6 book...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: And since a JTabbedPane is a Component, I can simply add the two JTabbedPanes to the CardLayout!

Comment: Another approach to selecting mode and level of difficulty is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9246664/230513).